# Three.js firstperson control start orientation

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to set an (variable) start orientation for the Three.js FirstPersonControls. Depending of the view the start orientation can be different. At the moment it always starts with vector3(0,0,0) as target. How can I set other orientations?

Answer (score 1):

As of `three.js` R101, it's possible to use `FirstPersonControls.lookAt()`. `FirstPersonControls.lat`, `FirstPersonControls.lon` and `FirstPersonControls.target` have been removed from the public API.

Comment: Despite the question is 5 years old, I do appriciate someone took the time to answer it

Comment: Sorry for the long delay. But finally there is a more user-friendly solution in `FirstPersonControls`.